# Являются ли прилагательные "чёрный" и "шёлковый" однородными, и нужна ли между ними запятая?

Tags: однородные-неоднородные-определения

...В свою спальню. Уже привычно находя себя взмокшим на чёрных шелковых простынях.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Однородные определения характеризуют предмет с одной стороны, а здесь две разные характеристики: цвет и материал. Запятая не нужна.

Answer (score 0):

"Чёрный" - качественное прилагательное, "шёлковый" (в данном предложении) - относительное прилагательное. Определения неоднородные, поэтому запятая не нужна.